# Is it possible to implement the script in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0, c#-2.0

I have a javascript code which conver the amount in to US format the same i would like to have in code behind can any one help me..

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function formatCurrency(num) {

num = num.toString().replace(/\$|\,/g,'');
if(isNaN(num))
num = "0";
sign = (num == (num = Math.abs(num)));
num = Math.floor(num*100+0.50000000001);
cents = num%100;
num = Math.floor(num/100).toString();
if(cents<10)
cents = "0" + cents;
for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((num.length-(1+i))/3); i++)
num = num.substring(0,num.length-(4*i+3))+','+
num.substring(num.length-(4*i+3));
return (((sign)?'':'-') + '$' + num + '.' + cents);
}
    </script>
```

Or if there is any easier method tell me. My actual requirement is to sum the two given amounts in the text boxes and to display the amount in 3rd text box.

For example if i have my 1st value as `123.12` by the above script i will get the display in my text box as `$123.12` and second as same to `$123.12` the output should be `$246.23`
can any one help me

Comment: why do you want to change the position of the code from a script to a code behind btw it would still remain a script...Do you want the code for this js in C#?

Comment: `@Abhi` Ya exaclty. Actually that script will remain as it is and fot the 3rd text box i don't want to use that `OnBlur` event i would like to place the amount i need immediately on `Textbox changed event`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a standard formatting for currency:

```
double n = 12345.67;
Console.WriteLine(n.ToString("C2", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")));
```

Ouptut:

```
$12,345.67
```

The standard for negative currency values is however to display it within parentheses, so if you want a negative sign instead you have to modify the culture:

```
CultureInfo info = new CultureInfo("en-US");
info.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;
double n = -12345.67;
Console.WriteLine(n.ToString("C2", info));
```

Ouptut:

```
-$12,345.67
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If `123.12 + 123.12 = 246.23` then your customers might not be to happy
2. What type is num actually? It looks like it's just a number, but you're converting it to string, removing `$` and `,` signs, just to add them later?
3. You can use `decimal.ToString(string format)` method, something like this should give you proper results:

```
static string Format(decimal x)
{
    return x.ToString("$#,0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}

//Usage:
string currencyFormatedNumber = Format(-41023.43M); //returns -$41,023.43
```

You could use something like this:

```
static string Format(decimal x)
{
       return x.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));
}
```

which is used to format currency, but it will format negative numbers as they should be formatted `($100.00)` means `-100.00 dollars`, which differs from your code.